# ActionResponse.sendRedirect is not working in Spring Portlet liferay?

Tags: spring, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I am using spring portlet version ( spring 4.1).

```
@ActionMapping(param="action=redirectTest")
 public void handleRenderRequest(ActionRequest request,ActionResponse response,Model model){
  System.out.printIn("the value coming");
  response.sendRedirect("https://www.google.com");
  System.out.printIn("the value coming");
 }
```

the sendRedirect is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Liferay's [limited redirect](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Redirect) configuration, configure accordingly and retry.

From that link, including the default values and documentation:

> Set this property to "ip" or "domain" for the redirect security
>   method. If set to "domain", the portal will only redirect users to
>   domains listed in the property "redirect.url.domain.allowed". If set
>   to "ip", the portal will only redirect to domains whose IP address
>   resolve to an IP address listed in the property
>   "redirect.url.ip.allowed". Defaults:
>
> ```
> redirect.url.security.mode=ip
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> redirect.url.security.mode=domain
> ```
>
> Input a list of comma delimited domains which the portal is allowed to
>   redirect to. Input a blank list to allow any domain. Specifying a
>   domain with a leading "*." allows redirects to subdomains. Defaults:
>
> ```
> redirect.url.domains.allowed=
> ```
>
> Input a list of comma delimited IPs which the portal is allowed to
>   redirect to. Input a blank list to allow any IP. SERVER_IP will be
>   replaced with the IP of the host server. Defaults:
>
> ```
> redirect.url.ips.allowed=127.0.0.1,SERVER_IP
> ```